# How to declare a collection resource model in swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I'm not sure about how I should do the declaration of the model for a collection resource on swagger.

The [spec](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) is missing some examples, so I'm guessing something like this:

```
  Class:
    required:
      - id
      - name
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
      name:
        type: string

  ClassList:
    type: array
    items:
      type:
        schema:
          $ref: Class
```

Then swagger editor shows the following generated documentation:

[image: Print from swagger editor]

Is it correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got the answer to this one already, but even for the sake of documentation:

```
ClassList:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: #/definitions/Class
```